# javascript Var error not working! click even

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

I am trying to get the link value or href from a popup page and add the content to the parent page in a text box. I don't knwo javascript well at all and dont understand why both links are not working.... There can be 2 items listed or there can be 500 so i need this to work with a dynamic list any help would be great! Thank you!!!!

Here is what i have.

**Pop up page....**

```
<a href="#item1" id="ddlNames"  name="ddlNames"><img src="link to item 1 image"> </a>
<a href="#item2" id="ddlNames"  name="ddlNames"> <img src="link to item 2 image"> </a>

<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetName() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").href;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

**Here is the code on the main page.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function SelectName() {
        popup = window.open("img_sel.php", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
        popup.focus();
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="image" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="Select Name" onclick="SelectName()" />
```

**Here is what i have now.....**

```
<?php 
$colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow"); 
foreach ($colors as $value)
  {
 echo "<a href=\"#$value\" id=\"$value\"  name=\"$value\"> $value </a>";
  }
?>

<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    cars=<?php echo json_encode($colors); ?>;
    function SetName() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");

        for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
        {   
        txtName.value = document.getElementById((cars[i])).href;
        }
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The `ddlNames` identifier occurs more than once in the popup; besides that, it should theoretically work ... are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: No it just flat out dont work. If i take out one of the Href links it works but wont with more then one.

Comment: Like I said before, you can't give the same id to multiple elements.

Comment: so...how would i get the url of one or the other if it is  getElementById("ddlNames") is used?

Comment: @Jack i posted my new code above i tried to use a loop?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear about what you want to put in the textbox.  Is it each color in the popup?  Do you always want to get all the colors or do you want the user to be able to choose one?

Comment: Also, in your loop code you will replace `txtName.value` each time.  Do you prefer to set it to element 0 and for elements 1..(n-1) do `txtName.value += (" " + document.getElementById((cars[i])).href)`

Comment: I want the url  #red or # green ect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same ids are not the good idea so you can do it this way, there is no need to use id.
[Here is full code](https://gist.github.com/pansarav/9244565)