# INSERT INTO not working what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

This script will not insert into my db table and i dont know why!!!! HELP 
I get no errors on the page just simply does not update in my bd

```
$con = new mysqli("***","*****","******","****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$ponum=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['po']);
$date=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
$to=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['to']);
$time=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['time']);
$vin=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['stk_vin']);
$reason=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['reason']);
$amount=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);
$empnum=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['emp']);
$manange$con->real_escape_string(r=$_POST['mananger']);
$accnum=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['acc']);
$store_location=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['store']);
$borr=$con->real_escape_string($_POST['borrowed']);



mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO fpo(ponum,date,to,time,vin,reason,amount,empnum,mananger,accnum,
store_location,borr)
VALUES ('$ponum','$date','$to','$time','$vin','$reason','$amount','$empnum','$mananger','$accnum','$store_location','$borr')");
```

Comment: $manange$con->real_escape_string(r=$_POST['mananger']; what is this?

Comment: @jens: obviously not, because there's NO error handling in that code, except for the initial connection attempt.

Comment: Do you ask for errors after executing the query?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 7):

You're using a reserved word => `to` 
in

```
INSERT INTO fpo (ponum,date,to,
                            ^^
```

Consult the following for a list of reserved words:
 - **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Escape it by wrapping it in backticks

```
INSERT INTO fpo (ponum,date,`to`,
```

or choose another word.

Do check errors with `or die(mysqli_error($con))`

including

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the top of your files.

Reference links:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**
- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php**
- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah, that little `to` was hard to find all bunched/tucked up in there.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you so much for your help!! @fred -ii- Thank you for your help as well1!! What is `to` do different then just to?

Comment: You're welcome. The backticks `\`` around `to` escapes a reserved word. @Kelly those must also be used if a table and/or column contains a space or hyphen.

Comment: @Kelly The question should be closed *with a tick* of the 'ol *you know what*, otherwise it will remain in the unanswered category.

Comment: @Kelly You're welcome. Yet, what I meant was to click the white checkmark till it turns green, just as you did in your other question with the accepted answer being http://stackoverflow.com/a/22059287/

Comment: @Kelly Fred just like a lot of other stack overflow users really dislike it when you get an answer but dont reward them for their time. if you are still using SO please accept this great answer